# Curl капча

Tags: веб-программирование, curl

Как получить адрес капчи из страницы с кодом (в теле html):

```
<img align="left" id="captcha_image" src="/ph/portfel/captcha/captcha_image.php?8fb9a36b625407a0e8af7efe8924af35" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
```

если в url самой капчи (при отображении в хроме) стоит
`http://www.arenda-piter.ru/ph/portfel/captcha/captcha_image.php?89f3a230447a2491acc7c4da2fcaabc7` (и фидлер, т.е. снифер, показывает запрос по этой ссылке, но как ее получить? )

Тело программы такое:
авторизация (с сохранением кук) успешно  
навигацияпо сайту, запрос на обновление (успешно)
получаю страницу с формой, содержащей капчу, а вот здесь не могу получить картинку капчи.

Пытался выловить из полученной html цифры после "src="/ph/portfel/captcha/captcha_image.php?" и сделать запрос "http://www.arenda-piter.ru/ph/portfel/captcha/captcha_image.php?" + код,
пытался без кода, ничего не выходит. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @nequt, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Получение

```
header("content-type: image/png");
echo file_get_contents('http://www.arenda-piter.ru/ph/portfel/captcha/captcha_image.php');
```

Конверт в base64

```
$url  = 'http://www.arenda-piter.ru/ph/portfel/captcha/captcha_image.php';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
echo 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```